# How to get multiple selected items from ListPicker and display them in MessageBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listpicker

Here is my code for the list of the items in a ListPicker. What I am trying to do is select one or more options and then after I press submit button I would like to display a MessageBox with the selected Items separated by commas. I also would like to store this value of the items selected to the database but, the first I am trying to do is populate the data into MessageBox.

```
                lstPickerType.Items.Add("Aircrafts");
                lstPickerType.Items.Add("Boats");
                lstPickerType.Items.Add("Cars");
                lstPickerType.Items.Add("Helicopters");
                lstPickerType.Items.Add("Electric Powered");
                lstPickerType.Items.Add("Gas Powered");
```

Here is the code that I have got to create a string from the list that is then displayed when the ListPicker is collapsed.

```
private void lstPickerType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    lstPickerType.SummaryForSelectedItemsDelegate = SummarizeItems;

}

private string SummarizeItems(IList items)
{
    if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
    {
        string summarizedString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            summarizedString += (string)items[i];

            // if the item is not last coma is added
            if (i != items.Count - 1)
                summarizedString += ", ";
        }
        return summarizedString;

    }
    else
        return "Nothing selected";
}
```

Finally for the button to display the MessageBox i have following code.

```
private void btnAddLocation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var item in this.lstPickerType.SelectedItems)
            {
                var items = new List<object>();
                MessageBox.Show(items.ToString());

            }
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to solve this issue. Thank You.

Comment: What's your particular problem? Is there an error? What's the code not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: Once I press the button I would like to get a message (for example if i choose aircrafts, boats, cars) I would like to get it displayed. instead of that I do get System.Collections.Generic.List'1 [System.Object]. I also get more messageboxes (if i choose three items i get 3 message boxes) Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty of C#, and i don't have visual studio in this pc, but I would achieve your result without the *selectionchanged* event in the listpicker.

Trythis code in the button click:
Edit: a cast was missing.

```cs
private void btnAddLocation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string r = "";
    for (int i=0; i<this.lstPickerType.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        r += ((ListPickerItem)this.lstPickerType.SelectedItems[i]).Content;
        if (i != this.lstPickerType.SelectedItems.Count - 1) 
            r += ", ";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(r);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it it is giving me 1 error on r += this.lstPickerType.SelectedItems[i].Content;
Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It works now I just had to do few adjustments such as deleting the .Content. Thank You very much for your help.